# User unintentionally deletes whole web part whenever she tries to delete single word in a text

Tags: 2013, delete, cewp

A certain user can't properly delete parts of text or even just simple words from a content editor web part.
Whenever she's editing a page and she selects one word from an entire piece of text inside a CEWP, and she then presses either the backspace button or delete button, it deletes the whole CEWP with everything in it. 
She has this in Internet Explorer, FireFox and Chrome. 
Why is this? Is this a setting on her computer? I couldn't duplicate the problem (tried with my account and my dummy account in three different browsers) so I'm thinking she might have done some sort of keyboard combination that causes this.
Any idea how I fix this? She needs to edit a lot of text on this particular page and she hasn't had this problem before. I can't find anything about this on Google, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this occur in all browsers?  It does sound like some keyboard custom configs.  You could also try another keyboard just to rule that out.

Comment: It does indeed occur in all browsers. However, when she uses my dummy account to edit the page, it doesn't occur anymore at all. Can such things be account-related?

Comment: I've never seen anything like that on a per-account basis.  What if she uses her account on another machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it no longer occurs if I give the user full administration rights on the subsite in which this page is present. Strange fix, but it does the trick.

Comment: Have her edit the web part first.  In order for me to edit the text in a CEWP on Wiki pages (not enterprise wiki's), I have to edit the web part (any web part, actually, as long as there's a web part properties open somewhere).